# MySQLDB in batch mode

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm running my python 2 mysql bridge with MySQL database. Now I am running an application to generate an overview of the current database state. For this I am sequentially querying the database in a for loop and store each reply for each query.

Can this be done more efficiently by generating all queries first, execute them and get all results in one go?

Comment: Please provide your code so we can see how you are connecting and how your query works?

Comment: Solved my problem it with moving the batch logic into the query.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. That sound like a good strategy.